# Entity framework: Db context scope and transaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, transactions

I have an MVC 5 web app which talks to my class library for db needs and the class library uses Entity Framework 6 for that.
Below are 2 methods from the class library.
Both of them are initiating a new context. How do I make 'em use only one context instead, without using class level variable?
Also, if these 2 methods were to save stuff, `context.SaveChanges()`, how can I wrap them both into one transaction, even if the save happens in different classes?

```
public int FindUnknownByName(string name, string language)
{
    using (var context = new ScriptEntities())
    {
        int languageId = this.FindLanguage(language);
        var script = context.scripts.Where(l => l.Name == name && l.Unknown == true && l.LanguageId == languageId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (script != null)
        {
            return script.Id;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public int FindLanguage(string language)
{
    using (var context = new ScriptEntities())
    {
        var lang = context.languages.Where(l => l.Name == language).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lang != null)
        {
            return lang.Id;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the context a private class field.

Comment: **without using class level variable**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why?

Comment: Was thinking if I could pass on the context as a variable. I could update method signature to accept dbcontext object, but wondering if there is a better way. And I also need to wrap the whole request into one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Make the context a private class variable.

```
private ScriptEntities context = new ScriptEntities()
public int FindUnknownByName(string name, string language)
{
        int languageId = this.FindLanguage(language);
        var script = context.scripts.Where(l => l.Name == name && l.Unknown == true && l.LanguageId == languageId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (script != null)
        {
            return script.Id;
        }
        return 0;
}

public int FindLanguage(string language)
{
        var lang = context.languages.Where(l => l.Name == language).FirstOrDefault();
        if (lang != null)
        {
            return lang.Id;
        }
        return 0;

}
```

**Also implement IDisposable and dispose context.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension methods:

```
public int FindUnknownByName(this ScriptEntities context, string name, string language)
{
        int languageId = context.FindLanguage(language);
        var script = context.scripts.Where(l => l.Name == name && l.Unknown == true && l.LanguageId == languageId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (script != null)
        {
            return script.Id;
        }
        return 0;.
}

public int FindLanguage(this ScriptEntities context, string language)
{
    var lang = context.languages.Where(l => l.Name == language).FirstOrDefault();
    if (lang != null)
    {
        return lang.Id;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

then:

```
using (var context = new ScriptEntities())
{
  var language = context.FindUnknownByName('name', 'language')
}
```